# Android Strings xml stores every value?

Tags: android

Do we have to place every text that we have to type in buttons or inputs or on plain surface of an activity.what happens if we don't provide values of text strings to strings xml??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what happens if we don't provide values of text strings to strings
>   xml??

you will get a lot of warnings from lint and no strings localization

Comment: ya i got warnings.even though i got warnings,if i run through emulator or in my phone,they are displaying as usual so have i supposed to give values for every text or forget about warnings and compile as usual?

Comment: of course you could ignore those but I strongly recommend to spend time in it. Now the effort is smaller than what you wold have to pay if you decide to id after you finish your project

Answer (score 1):

Using `strings.xml` is mainly for localization, it's easy to translate a XML file and use it, not using `strings.xml` is a headache later on when you want to translate your app.

You may not use it, but maybe later you'll regret it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides localization, it's very handy to have all strings located in the same place, when for instance, you have to change some label or correct some messages displayed to users.

Looking for strings in the code afterward could be a real pain when thousand of lines of code are produced.